What is the meaning of 真数导弹?
What is the meaning of 真数导弹? I hear it many times in news videos about Ukraine.
Some examples:
...飞速导弹进行了回忆，那么呃，21号啊，也就是21号普京总统的专门就这个真数导弹呢？进行了一个啊非常正式的声明，那么普及在这个声明里啊，非常明确的向西方发出了信号，就是说啊，第一呢？
...装备升级对无菌源的方式来进一步的加固美国的反俄立场首先呢说到这个真数导弹的使用很明显乌克兰更多关注到的并不是他军事方面的效果而是关注到他具有政治和战略方面的目标而现在呢乌克兰索要防空系统...
Dictionaries say that 真数 means logarithm and 导弹 missile, but I cannot make them make sense.
Maybe it is 针束导弹?

most likely, it is (超)音速导弹 - supersonic missile

I am sure that I hear zhen1 shu4 dao3 dan4. Maybe zhen1 is about 榛 = hazel, shu4 is a classifier, and it is about the new Russian hypersonic missile meaning hazel tree = oreshnik = орешник?

It's 榛树导弹. '榛树' is a code name of a kind of missile of Russia. I just made a little bit of searching in internet. '榛树导弹' means a missile that named '榛树'.

maybe the actual text is 战术导弹, Zhànshù rather than Zhēn shù? I suppose `_>`

There is no “真数导弹” in Chinese. Please give source of “真数导弹” about I hear it many times in news videos about Ukraine.

你问题中的中文语句不通顺。
你说的真数导弹应该是榛树导弹，见下面的第二张图片，我猜测这个榛树应该是由俄罗斯语言翻译过来的， 它是导弹的名字 。
第一张图片

第二张图片

